# How can i get two route details in one jQuery separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

**when i click the check box want display Full Name;**

```
      input type="text" id="demonum" size="05">
      <button type="button" onclick="load_doc()">click</button><br><br>

      <input type="checkbox" id ="check" >
```

**I got my route results like this**

```
function load_doc(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var stId = document.getElementById('demonum').value;
//
      URL1 = `http://localhost:8082/students/${stId}`;
      URL2 = `http://localhost:8082/getFullStudentDetails/${stId}`;

      $.get(URL2,function(responseText){

            $("#indexno").text(responseText.ID);//this came from URL1
            $("#pname").text(responseText.Name);//this came from URL1
            $("#pgrade").text(responseText.Grade);//this came from URL1
            $("#fullname").text(responseText.pName); //this came from URL2
        });
      });
    }
```

***- Following is the process!***

- "demonum" is textbox when i enter the ID number there it go to the stID variable.
- Then it join to the above URL1 & URL2.
- After that it give the results according to the ID number.
- That details display in a table i link them using following id,
- $("#indexno")
- $("#pname")
- $("#pgrade")
- $("#fullname")

**Now when i enter ID number 1 it desplay ID,Name,Grade accordng to the  $.get(URL,function(responseText) if i change URL2 that give ID,Name,Grade,fullname**

- Now i want to do like this.....I think i have to get URL2 because there are ID,Name,Grade,Full name, IF am i right.....give me a answer according to the example that i gave!

---

EX :- if i get URL1 then display ID,Name,Grade. then i want to do when i click the checkbox in that time i want to desplay Full name.

Comment: What actually do you need, its hard to understand

Comment: there is a two route. that route i got to URL1 & URL2 variables. so that two variables (two routes) give different result ok! URL1 give ID,Name,Grade but URL2 give ID,Name,Grade,Full name.....think if i get URL2 result want to be like this it display ID,Name,Grade when i press the checkbox then want to display Full name

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with JQuery `$.when` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button[type=button]").on('click', function(){
    var isChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked')==true;
    var stId      = $("#demonum").val();
    var URL1      = `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${stId}`;
    var URL2      = `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${stId}`; 

    $.when(
      $.get(URL1),
      // if checked then call second url
      (isChecked?($.get(URL2)):null)
    )
    .then(function(responseURL1, responseURL2) { 
      console.log('responseURL1', responseURL1)
      console.log('responseURL2', responseURL2)

      $("#indexno").text(responseURL1[0].id);//this came from URL1
      $("#pname").text(responseURL1[0].username);//this came from URL1
      $("#pgrade").text(responseURL1[0].phone);//this came from URL1

      if (responseURL2)
      {
        $("#fullname").text(responseURL2[0].title); //this came from URL2
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="demonum" size="05">
<button type="button">click</button><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id ="check"> 

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Post Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="indexno">-</td>
      <td id="pname">-</td>
      <td id="pgrade">-</td>
      <td id="fullname">-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: responceURL not response values!

Comment: then() returns a new promise where you can filter the response. Please check in console.log(responseURL1)

Comment: I have added code snippet and demo URL please check it now.